# systemjs-webpack-interop requires webpack@>=5.0.0-beta.15 and output.libraryTarget set to 'system'

Tags: webpack, single-spa

I'm getting the error in the title when trying to build micro-frontend structure use single-spa:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "single-spa-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-single-spa": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
```

Any idea why?

this is my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      libraryTarget:'system'
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.externals(["vue", "vue-router", "single-spa"])
  }
};
```